# How to make Container View scrollable using Scroll View in Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, layout, uiscrollview, constraints, xcode8

I am making chat app and have create persona component which is implemented to view with `Container view`

[image: Create persona component]
[image: View with container view]

And when form fits device screen everything is ok, but when I rotate iPhone to landscape orientation it is not enough screen space so I used `Scroll view` to make it scrollable. But as I understood `Container view` resizes with `Scroll view` so it becomes not scrollable

Comment: Have you set the contentSize?

Comment: @RodrigoMorbach, I want to make it responsive depending on screen size, so it doesn't have exact size

Comment: I see. I think you change the content size as the screen changes both orientation and size.

Comment: @RodrigoMorbach, I think this is cause I set bottom constraint for container view on scroll view, but without that Xcode show error

Comment: @RodrigoMorbach, I again googled my problem and got some solution which also didn't help: http://nn.lv/sekz